# Not able to install google play services!

Tags: root-access, google-play-services

I can't install google play services, either from play store or from a downloaded APK.

When I downloaded it from play store, the following error was displayed:

> incompatible with other apps using same user id

I can't login to my Google+ account.

I can't factory reset my phone as my progress in game clash of clans will be lost so other solutions are preferable.

I'm rooted.

Android version: 4.0.3

Model: xoloA500

Comment: If the error you're getting includes an error code (usually a number), you could check our [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) for a possible solution (it lists the most common errors).

Comment: Possibly your installation of Android's lost track of what apps have what UIDs? In most custom recoveries (TWRP definitely) there's an option to 'fix permissions', which might fix this problem.